# Explain SQL Syntax: Select tbl.*

Tags: sql, syntax, subquery

I have a query I don't really understand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TBL.*
FROM (
SELECT
     attribute1,
     attribute2,
     etc...
FROM table) TBL
```

I'm guessing TBL is giving the result set a name, but why is it necessary in the select statement and what does the '.' do?

Comment: It's not necessary at all and serves no practical purpose. Perhaps this was somebody's way to get around a strict rule that prevented `select *` but allowed `select tbl.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot `.` indicates that you are reffering to a column (or all columns) of the table TBL (in your case the subquery)

The outer query just applies `DISTINCT` to every column of the inner query

Note that in your case it doesn't make much sense to have a nested query, you can rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT att1, att2, ... FROM table
```

Also note that if you are not using aggregates, your query is functionally equivalent to a Group by:

```
SELECT att1, att2, ... FROM table GROUP BY att1, att2, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there is no difference between `TBL.*` and `*`, but suppose your query was something like

```
 Select * from Customer 
   Inner Join Country on Country.ID = Customer.CountryID
  where Country.Code = 'UK'
```

This will return every column in **both** Customer and Country tables whereas

```
 Select Customer.* from Customer 
   Inner Join Country on Country.ID = Customer.CountryID
  where Country.Code = 'UK'
```

will only return the columns in the customer table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Fixed now (Getting C# and Sql syntax mixed up)

Answer (score 0):

Same as this one too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TBL.*
FROM (
    SELECT
         attribute1,
         attribute2,
         etc...
    FROM (
        SELECT
            attribute1,
            attribute2,
            etc...
        FROM table
        ) TBL2
    ) TBL
```

Kind of silly, isn't it?

TBL and TBL2 are names that only "exist" for the purposes of referring to things inside the query. I was pointing out that anytime you mention a table in the `FROM` clause as `table TBLn` it's basically equivalent to saying `(SELECT * FROM table) TBLn`.

There are many good reasons to embed these expressions (aka derived tables, nested views, inline views) inside of queries but their practical value becomes more obvious only when you look at an example that not as pointless as the one you've got there.

I don't know of any platforms that don't *require* a name like `TBL`. In some cases it would be handy to just leave it out. In my query there was no ambiguity in column references to I didn't even have to mention `TBL2' at all. And in that sense I'm not "doing" anything at all.

In a procedural language I could make a whole cascade of pointless variable assignments (say `a1 = 42; a2 = a1; a3 = a2; a4 = a3; a5 = a4; ...`) and the compiler will likely realize that most of the variables never get used and so it won't bother to waste the memory or CPU cycles on them. It essentially recognizes that you weren't really "doing" anything with them. Don't treat SQL like a procedural language, but in a similar way the SQL parser (and optimizer) is going to resolve all those temporary/shorthand names and figure out how the best way to return the results of the query.

Comment: What are you doing with 'TBL2'? Is this a way of naming the result set? 'TBL' is not an actual table in my database which is why I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

As I see that question starter still does not understand. I believe that he knows some OOP basics.
Let's say you have an array of some class in your OOP programming language. Let's say that it is something like:

```
<classA>Array[] TBL = new classA();
```

The class would be something like:

```
class classA {
 int   attribute1,
 string    attribute2,
...
}
```

Then let's say that you have the data in that class already, so the array TBL  has some elements inside.
If you want to get some elements from this array, you are doing something like `TBL[1].getAttribute1, TBL[1].getAttribute2....`

So, in your question you have array of data that in SQL world is called as SUBQUERY and you give name to it as 'TBL' (you can choose any name you like).

```
(
SELECT
     attribute1,
     attribute2,
     etc...
FROM table) TBL
```

Now you want to get elements from this array. By SQL syntax you need to specify what exactly do you want to get. For example: TBL.attribute1, TBL.attribute2, ... But if you want to show all elements of this array, you just use * instead. --> TBL.*

Now let's comeback to the SUBQUERY. Instead of it you can use tables/views/functions. All of them can be named with any name you like (name = alias). And later you can use this alias for easier code writing.